# ActionBarWindow "Unable to resolve static field"

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am getting error when I try to run a android application with action bar.

> VFY: unable to resolve static field 1538 (ActionBarWindow) in
>   Landroid/support/v7/appcompat/R$styleable;
>
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   android.support.v7.appcompat.R$styleable

Any help or suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: This looks like a library import issue. Are your importing the proper version of the support library correctly ?

Comment: I think I imported all the necessary jar library needed.

Comment: I don't agree with the reason for closing this question. There is enough info to answer it - the approved answer below is exactly what is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you very sure that u has followed line by line of section Adding libraries with resources of this [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html)?

Answer (score 0):

Did you make the activity have the appcompat theme in manifest?

```
activity android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"
```

Comment: No I did not do that. Its just regular manifest file.

Comment: It didnt work... thanks for help..