# Eclipse Android java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm trying to do the Android tutorial on the Android developer site ([here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html?hl=p)). I installed the Eclpise/Android SDK bundle on the site, but when I try to run the autogenerated code, which is supposed to just display "Hello World," I get a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError. I haven't written any code myself yet.

Here's the logcat log of the error:

```
09-02 17:44:15.430: D/dalvikvm(872): Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
09-02 17:44:15.780: W/dalvikvm(872): VFY: unable to resolve static field 1864 (ActionBarWindow) in Landroid/support/v7/appcompat/R$styleable;
09-02 17:44:15.780: D/dalvikvm(872): VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x0004
09-02 17:44:15.790: D/AndroidRuntime(872): Shutting down VM
09-02 17:44:15.790: W/dalvikvm(872): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb2a99d70)
09-02 17:44:15.800: E/AndroidRuntime(872): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-02 17:44:15.800: E/AndroidRuntime(872): Process: com.example.test1, PID: 872
09-02 17:44:15.800: E/AndroidRuntime(872): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.appcompat.R$styleable
09-02 17:44:15.800: E/AndroidRuntime(872):  at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:106)
09-02 17:44:15.800: E/AndroidRuntime(872):  at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:57)
09-02 17:44:15.800: E/AndroidRuntime(872):  at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreate(ActionBarActivity.java:99)
09-02 17:44:15.800: E/AndroidRuntime(872):  at com.example.test1.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:13)
09-02 17:44:15.800: E/AndroidRuntime(872):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5242)
09-02 17:44:15.800: E/AndroidRuntime(872):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
09-02 17:44:15.800: E/AndroidRuntime(872):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2161)
09-02 17:44:15.800: E/AndroidRuntime(872):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2258)
09-02 17:44:15.800: E/AndroidRuntime(872):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:138)
09-02 17:44:15.800: E/AndroidRuntime(872):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1209)
09-02 17:44:15.800: E/AndroidRuntime(872):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
09-02 17:44:15.800: E/AndroidRuntime(872):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
09-02 17:44:15.800: E/AndroidRuntime(872):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5026)
09-02 17:44:15.800: E/AndroidRuntime(872):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-02 17:44:15.800: E/AndroidRuntime(872):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
09-02 17:44:15.800: E/AndroidRuntime(872):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
09-02 17:44:15.800: E/AndroidRuntime(872):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
09-02 17:44:15.800: E/AndroidRuntime(872):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This is my first question, so please let me know if there's anything else I should include.

Comment: It seems the same error that in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21591169/actionbarwindow-unable-to-resolve-static-field) question, that is fixed Adding libraries with resources of this [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html).

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22526925/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-android-support-v7-appcompat-rstyleable